# mongoDB PUT and DELETE getting 404's

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

My GET and POST requests are working just fine in my Postman tests, but when I try to do a PUT and DELETE request I keep getting 404's.  Does anyone know why?  This is my bucketListItems.js code.  My app is listening at http://localhost:3000, MongoDB database Connected,  so and and so forth.  I am currently inserting this code from a tutorial and I do not see any differences in the two.

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const BucketListItem = require("../../models/BucketListItem");

const router = Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const bucketListItems = await BucketListItem.find();
    if (!bucketListItems) throw new Error("No bucketListItems");
    const sorted = bucketListItems.sort((a, b) => {
      return new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime();
    });
    res.status(200).json(sorted);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const newBucketListItem = new BucketListItem(req.body);
  try {
    const bucketListItem = await newBucketListItem.save();
    if (!bucketListItem)
      throw new Error("Something went wrong saving the bucketListItem");
    res.status(200).json(bucketListItem);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    const response = await BucketListItem.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body);
    if (!response) throw Error("Something went wrong");
    const updated = { ...response.doc, ...req.body };
    res.status(200).json(updated);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  try {
    const removed = await BucketListItem.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    if (!removed) throw Error("Something went wrong ");
    res.status(200).json(removed);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my server.js code...

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const PORT = 3000;
const mongoUri =
  "mongodb+srv://admnin:myFakePass12@provaca.5vjb9.mongodb.net/mevn-stack?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const bucketListItemRoutes = require("./routes/api/bucketListItems");

app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("tiny"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose
  .connect(mongoUri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB database Connected ... "))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use("/api/bucketListItems", bucketListItemRoutes);
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));

app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);
```

Comment: Can you share the endpoint you're calling ?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/bucketListItems/

is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, you need to pass `id` of the document in the endpoint that is need to be updated/deleted.
eg. localhost:3000/api/bucketListItems/4c26ed9032f6bf001d5ce14b

Comment: that makes so much sense now! thank you!